# Add points to a live graph from a different file

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to get a live graph working in my code.

I can get a live graph working when everything is within the same python file, though when I try to separate the graph class into its own python file, the graph doesn't update. I have no real indication of why the graph isn't updating, but I think I may be creating a bunch of LogGraph objects as opposed to adding points to the actual LogGraph which is in `my.kv`, but I am not sure how to not do that.

My actual code is a bit involved and confusing, so I mocked up an example code here which should be behaving exactly the same:

**main.py**

```
from math import sin
import kivy
from kivy_garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from data import startdata

class MainWindow(Screen):

    def pressrun(self):
        self.ids.runlbl.text = 'Started'
        startdata()

    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        wm.add_widget(MainWindow())
        return wm

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WindowManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

wm = WindowManager()
kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv**

```
#: import LogGraph graphs.LogGraph
<MainWindow>:
    id: main
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        LogGraph:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Button:
                text: "Start Data Gen"
                on_release:
                    root.pressrun()
            Label:
                id: runlbl
                text: "Not Started"
```

**graphs.py**

```
from kivy_garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot

class LogGraph(Graph):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LogGraph, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.xlabel = 'X'
        self.ylabel = 'Y'
        self.x_ticks_major = 25
        self.x_ticks_minor = 5
        self.x_grid_label = True
        self.y_ticks_major = 1
        self.y_grid_label = True
        self.xmin = 0
        self.xmax = 100
        self.ymin = 0.1
        self.ymax = 10
        self.ylog = True
        self.x_grid = True
        self.y_grid = True
        self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
        self.add_plot(self.plot)
        self.plot.points = [(1,1)]

    def update_xaxis(self,xmin = 0):
        self.xmin = xmin
        self.xmax = xmin + 10

    def update_yaxis(self,ymin = 0):
        self.ymin = ymin
        self.ymax = ymin + 10

    def update_points(self, point, *args):
        self.plot.points.append([point,point])
        # x axis resize
        if point > self.xmax:
            self.update_xaxis(self.xmax)
        # y axis resize
        if point > self.ymax:
            self.update_yaxis(self.ymax)
```

**data.py**

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial
from graphs import LogGraph

class DataStore():
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 1
        self.dataarray = []

    def start(self):
        self.clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self.getData, 1/60)

    def cancel(self):
        self.clock.cancel()

    def wait(self):
        print('Waited!')

    def getData(self):
        i = self.i + 1/60
        LogGraph.update_points(LogGraph(), i)
        pass

def startdata():
    ds = DataStore()
    ds.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three main problems with your code:

1. Your code `kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")` is loading the `my.kv` file a second time. It will be loaded automatically because the file is named correctly for that to happen. You should eliminate that code.
2. Your scheduled calls to `DataStore.getData()` will not work because your `DataStore` instance is not saved anywhere, and so it gets garbage collected.
3. The `getData()` method of `DataStore` creates a new instance of `LogGraph` each time it runs, but does not use the instance of `LogGraph` that is in your  GUI.

To fix these problems, start by adding to your `kv` to allow access:

```
#: import LogGraph graphs.LogGraph
<MainWindow>:
    id: main
    name: 'main'  # added to enable access
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        LogGraph:
            id: graph  # added to enable access
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Button:
                text: "Start Data Gen"
                on_release:
                    root.pressrun()
            Label:
                id: runlbl
                text: "Not Started"
```

Then in the `startdata()` method, add a return

```
def startdata():
    ds = DataStore()
    ds.start()

    # return the DataStore instance so it can be saved
    return ds
```

Then save the returned `DataStore` in the `pressrun()` method:

```
def pressrun(self):
    self.ids.runlbl.text = 'Started'
    self.dataStore = startdata()
```

And the `getData()` method must be modified to access the `LogGraph` that is in the GUI:

```
def getData(self, dt):  # time interval argument is required
    self.i += dt

    # access the LogGraph instance in the GUI
    lg = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('main').ids.graph
    lg.update_points(self.i)
    # LogGraph.update_points(LogGraph(), i)
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! I never realized you could call get_running_app() outside of the main python file. Taught me a new trick and fixed parts of my code that I didn't even realize were inefficient!